# Force one reducer in AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce

How do I ensure that there's only reducer for my EMR Streaming job? Is there any way to do this from the web frontend when I'm creating a new Jobflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure Hadoop in the bootstrap action using the --arg flag.  Specifically to your question you can set the mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum to 1.

```
elastic-mapreduce --create --alive \
      --name "Configure Jobflow" \
      --bootstrap-actions s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/configure-hadoop
      --arg mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum=2
```